# ConstantScoreRangeQuery in Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, legacy

How is Lucene's [ConstantScoreRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/ConstantScoreRangeQuery.html) better than the old [RangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/RangeQuery.html)?

In what case should you use still use RangeQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the RangeQuery documentation in your link, 
A ConstantScoreRangeQuery:

- is faster than RangeQuery.
- does not cause a BooleanQuery.TooManyClauses exception if the range of values is large.
- does not influence scoring based on the scarcity of individual terms that may match.

Suppose you are interested in scarcer terms being scored higher (say you are looking in a range of hours, but want the scarcer hours to be scored higher - maybe you are looking for a "slow" period of the day to run a backup process). In that case the older RangeQuery seems preferable.

The next generation will be the [TrieRangeQuery](http://www.marcsturlese.com/2009/04/08/lucene-trierangequery/), currently in the contrib section. It will probably part of the Lucene 2.9 core. It provides faster range queries than both other methods.